# C++, why is array=ptr legal?

Tags: c++, syntax

Recently i saw this piece of code. Shouldnt this line be a compile error?`char arr[4]="Abc";`

What happens here? Is arr a pointer? is the char* copied into an array on stack? is this legal in all version of C++ (and what about C?). I tested and seen this works in VS and code pad which i believe uses gcc

-edit- Just for fun I tried replacing "Abc" with a static const char *. It gave me an invalid initializer error.

```
int main()
{
    int j=97;
    char arr[4]="Abc";
    printf(arr,j);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, arr is a pointer. The difference is that arr[] allocates space on the stack for the block of characters where *arr would expect you to allocate the space for the block.

Comment: @Tergiver: No, it's not. It's an array. An array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer, an array is not a pointer.

Comment: @Tergiver: No. `arr` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: @GMan: An array is a block of bytes located somewhere in memory. You cannot have a block of bytes (of any kind) without a pointer to that block. Well.. you could, but you'd never be able to access it.

Comment: @Tergiver: You are wrong. Yes, an array uses a contiguous chunk of memory. After that you're wrong. By your argument, *all* types are pointers because you couldn't access them without a pointer to their memory. `int i; // this must be a pointer, otherwise we couldn't access it`

Comment: @GMan: "int i" is a pointer to a 4-byte block of memory. But now we're just getting semantic. The C++ compiler doesn't distinguish between arr[] and *arr, it does treat intrinsic types differently.

Comment: @Tergiver: Uh no. You really think `i` in `int i;` is a pointer? This is the C++ type system we're talking about, we aren't talking about implementation details. `i` above has the type `int`, always and forever. `int arr[4]` has the type `int[4]`, not `int*`. They are different. How something may or may not be implemented is irrelevant to the type system. Arrays are not pointers. Also, an `int` isn't necessarily exactly 4 bytes. Nor is a byte necessarily exactly 8 bits.

Comment: @Tergiver. The compiler does (and has to) distinguish between arrays and pointers. Try compiling: `extern int a[]; int f(int n) { return a[n]; }` and then try compiling `extern int* a; int f(int n) { return a[n]; }`. They generate different object code.

Comment: The failboat has sailed. FYI a pointer means you have a value and you use an assembly instruction to instead get the value at the value location.

Comment: @Tergiver: Sorry, but that can be said about absolutely any variable in C: you can't access it unless you have a pointer to it. Right? Wrong. You are mixing the concept of *lvalue* with the concept of a *pointer*. "Pointer" in C means a totally different thing. Array is not a pointer, it is an *lvalue*: an object with a location in memory, which is known to the compiler. Which is why you can access it. You don't need any "pointers" to perform the access.

Comment: @Everyone: I'll concede only for the sake of peace. The problem is the definition of 'pointer'. Mine differs from yours. Is there somewhere in the C++ specification that defines the word pointer unambiguously? I don't know.

Comment: @acid: Assembly has nothing to do with anything in the language. A pointer is a value that holds the address of another value. Where does assembly come into play? Never. @Tergiver: §8.3.1.

Comment: Which spec are you (GMan and Charles) referring to? I'm guessing you mean ISO 14882:2003 which I don't have (free) access to.

Comment: @Tergiver: In this case, the C++0x draft works as well. While you're at it, read §8.3.4. That talks about arrays.

Comment: Ok, given the definitions of 'pointer' in §8.3.1 together with 'array' in §8.3.4, I will stand corrected. arr[] is not a pointer as defined by C++. By the way, Wikipedia has a link to 14882:2010 (draft).

Comment: @GMan: I assume for the most part people share the pointer meaning with the assembly meaning. A value that holds the address to the value you want. Taking extra cpu cycles to read the value(addr) the another to access it (either reading or writing).

Comment: @acid: You should probably get out of the habit of inserting implementation details into language details. *How* pointers work is not defined by the language, *what* they are is. If something you're doing in C++ hinges on an implementation detail, you need to tread carefully.

Comment: "*If something you're doing in C++ hinges on an implementation detail, you need to tread carefully*" - As an embedded systems software engineer for nearly 20 years (primarily), I do a lot that hinges on implementation details. However, and this might explain my incorrect view of 'pointer' in the context of C++, I actually work quite a lot in bare-bones, ANSI C, as well as assembly.

Comment: @Tergiver: Bare bones FTW. Sometimes annoying. I was working on an embeded system before and the hardware documents were a bit messy. LibC (i forget what its good, was it libc?) worked great since it was all raw memory access. When we did something in HW sometimes it would do something unexpected but we can always rely on how C/C++ worked :) (even after optimization!)

Comment: @Tergiver: I don't doubt you do, but again: tread lightly. The moment you assume some implementation-specific detail, you may no longer call it C++, but implementation-specific C++.

Comment: @GMan: There is one benefit embedded systems have over general purpose computers: You (usually) only have to support one specific piece of hardware =)

Comment: @GMan: Did you know you can do memset and memcpy on a &vector[0]? and cast it as (char*) safely? i bet you didnt or think thats implementation-specific ;). There is a LOT of things not specified but there is a lot more specified. Also string.size() is O(1) even though it may not store the length anywhere in the class. (endptr-startptr can be used as well as size() return somevar & 0xFFFFFF;)

Comment: @acid: Uh, I did know that...? What made you think I didn't? You can of course only do that if the elements within the vector are POD types. I'm not sure what your point is. Is there one?

Comment: @GMan: What made me think you didnt? quite frankly because you seem to think more things are implementation-specific and a lot less define in the standard. My point was the standard defines a lot. And what made me really think you didnt know that. When you said and i quote "'\0' is zero depends on character encoding" and "I mean why do people also use '\0' instead of just 0? "

Comment: @acid: I know we say this same code---*exactly* the same code including the strangely placed `getch`---in another SO question very recently. You should have linked to that question.

Comment: @acid: No, I never said anything of the sort. *You're* the one hinging on implementation-specific things. When you say "it's allocated on the stack", that's implementation-specific. And you must have missed the part where I opened the standard and corrected my understanding. And you clearly still miss the point of that question, which Thomas and Martin both answered. You think string literals are pointers, and you're telling me I don't know what's going on? All I said is the moment you bring in implementation-details, you aren't talking about C++ the language. Assembly, for example, isn't C++.

Comment: Come on, is this question serious?

Comment: The failboat has once again sailed.

Comment: @dmckee: actually i linked this page from there and its shows up on the link section above. Heres the link to that strange code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844623/c-programming-language-array-pointer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array = ptr` is not a legal assignment (if `array` has an array type and `ptr` has the corresponding pointer type). In the code you have shown, though, the `=` introduces an initializer as it is part of a declaration. It is not an assignment.

It is legal to initialize an array of `char` with a string constant.

Comment: so this is an array on the stack?

Comment: @acidzombie24: From a language point of view `array` has automatic storage duration so it lives until the end of the scope in which it is declared. Colloquially, it's on the stack.

Comment: I didnt think of trying this but heres some code showing it is using the stack http://codepad.org/wTZvSYEZ

Comment: @GMan: If it was a pointer then the function called the 2nd time would print Azb in the first printf getting the output AbcAzcA**z**cAzc. However in VS i get a access violation error at runtime and codepad seems to ignore writes to const char* http://codepad.org/4vs0B43f

Comment: @acid: The line `arr[1] = 'z';` invokes undefined behavior. You cannot draw any conclusions from this program, at all.

Answer (score 4):

String literal is not a pointer. String literal is an character array. So, what you have in your example is an `array = array` *initialization*, not an `array = pointer` as you seem to believe.

Yet in general it is indeed illegal to initialize one array with another array, in both C and C++.

However, in both C and C++ there's one exception from that rule: character arrays *can* be initialized with string literals. (Note: *initialization* is allowed; assignment won't work). Each element of the array gets initailized with the corresponding character from the literal (which also implicitly include a terminating zero character at the end). In C++ it is required that the recipient array's size has enough space for the terminating zero. In C the terminating zero is allowed to "fall off", if the recipient array is one character short.

Also, you are not required to specify the array size explicitly. You can do

```
char arr[] = "Abc";
```

and the compiler will automatically figure out that you need a 4 element array.

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to

```
char arr[4] = {'A', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

which is in turn equivalent to:

```
char arr[4];
arr[0] = 'A';
arr[1] = 'b';
arr[2] = 'c';
arr[3] = 0;
```

Comment: That should be `'\0'`, strictly speaking that doesn't have to be 0.

Comment: No, '\0' means 0. It is the character #0, which has the numeric value of 0.

Comment: @Thomas: Whether or not `'\0'` is zero depends on character encoding. It isn't necessarily so. Or maybe not. Looking...

Comment: I'm convinced that @GMan is about to discover that he is wrong on this one.

Comment: @Charles: Ha, yup. I remember getting a scolding from someone reputable on SO a long time ago when I used 0 instead of `'\0'`, and they said it might not be the same. I can't remember who, but they were wrong. The null-terminator does indeed have to be 0, as it should. Bah, didn't know how to check things back then.

Comment: @GMan: no, '\0' equals 0, no matter which character encoding you use.

Comment: The '\0' is actually an octal escape sequence. It is literally the octal number 0. From n1336 See Appendix A.1.5 Section (6.4.4.4) character constants

Comment: @Martin: How did that become a de facto method of NIL instead of just 0?

Comment: One possibility: Because zero is a logic false. This lets you do stuff like while(*str++) which loops until the character '\0' is reached.

Comment: @Thomas: I mean why do people also use `'\0'` instead of just 0?

Comment: @GMan: '\0' means its a char of the escape \0 (which AFAIK is legal in char and string quotes). \VALUE is a oct value unless it starts with \xVALUE. It says so here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/lex.html  search `escape-sequence:` which shows simple, oct and hex escapes. I dont know how ppl thought it was something other then oct or hex. I never heard of 'encoding' on a hard escape before ;P

Comment: @acid: Once again, I reiterate the question: How did '\0' become a de facto method of acquiring 0 for strings, instead of just directly doing 0? I'm not asking how escapes work.

Comment: Because it allows you to do this: "Hello, world!\0", even though the "\0" is explicit in C. And it makes it obvious to the reader that you intend to compare the value in the string against NUL, not just '0'.

Comment: @GMan: Maybe because 0 is an int so there is an implicit conversion. While '\0' is a char.

Answer (score 1):

Character arrays can be initialized with string literals, it just assigns each element character by character. It's just a language feature.

---

And no, `arr` is not a pointer. It's an array. `"Abc"` is a string literal, which is also a character array.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Arrays are arrays. Pointers are pointers. Arrays are a collection of contiguous elements, pointers point.

Comment: @Thomas: they are not. `typeid(int*) != typeid(int[10])` Arrays are convertible to pointers though.

Comment: An array has an implicit conversion to a pointer.  An `int` has an implicit conversion to `double`.  Would you therefore say that an `int` IS a `double`?

Comment: Ah, I must be getting confused. An array refers to an "array" of memory, but the actual variable points to the first item. That's why arr[x] is equivalent to *(arr + x) - right?

Comment: @Thomas: It's equivalent because the language says so. This is a poor example, but hopefully gets the point across: Imagine `int a[10]` was `struct int[10] { int e0; int e1; ... int e9; } a;`. It's just a big type. And it also happens to be implicitly convertible to a pointer to `e0`. `a + x` won't work, but `&e0 + x` will. So the compiler uses that implicit conversion and does so.

Comment: @Thomas O: Incorrect. Array variable *is* the entire block. There's no pointer there of any kind. `arr[x]` is equivalent to `*(arr + x)` because `arr` can be *implicitly converted* to a pointer "on the fly", not because it itself is a pointer. It is not.

Comment: @Thomas it was the whole point of arrays that they are *not* pointers which caused them to be adopted in C. If array variables were pointers, you couldn't stick arrays into structs and map them to external resources. After all, what you would map would be the 4/8 bytes of the pointer only. See http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html for details (scroll to "Embryonic C").